# OpenCV's cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) changes to unreachable timestamp?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to read frames from a certain timestamp to a certain timestamp, problem is that just after setting it up to start at *800 milliseconds* for example:

```
start_time = 0.8
end_time = 4
MILLISECONDS = 1000
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, float(start_time * MILLISECONDS))
```

Now I try and check where it is with:

```
cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
```

Which returns:

```
13346.680013346679
```

and according to [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da7c2fa550ba270713fca1405397b90ae0), that flag stands for

> Current position of the video file in milliseconds.

Which is kind of confusing because my entire video is 4 seconds long i.e. *4000 milliseconds*, the entire code snippet is:

```
def load_video(path, start_time, end_time, skip_frames=False):
    MILLISECONDS = 1000
    frame_pos = 0

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, float(start_time * MILLISECONDS))
    frames = []
    try:
        while cap.isOpened() and cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) <= float(end_time * MILLISECONDS):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            # OpenCV default capturing is on BGR format,
            # if RGB is needed then un-comment this line:
            # frame = frame[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
            frames.append(frame)
            if skip_frames:
                # If we want to take every 5th frame (where there is a an action documented).
                frame_pos += 12
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_pos)

    finally:
        cap.release()
    return np.array(frames)
```

The point is to read from a certain timestamp to a certain timestamp, but the 2nd condition in the `while` statement obviously isn't satisfied since `13346.680013346679 > 4000` from the get go, **and most strangely `ret, frame = cap.read()` actually reads a frame** when I'm executing it in the debugger just before stepping to the `while` check.

So what I'm doing wrong here?

P.S

The video file is `.avi` & 60fps.

Comment: "seeking" in video files is hard. you need to learn about keyframes. also, OpenCV uses ffmpeg, and ffmpeg is generally agreed to be underdocumented and hard to understand. that may be one of the reasons OpenCV has trouble using ffmpeg correctly... but ffmpeg itself probably has bugs (no software doesn't but... eh). -- do not rely on this working. read all frames in sequence. -- use `ffprobe -of json` and show format and streams of your video file

Comment: further, seeking by frame number is often impossible because that information does either not exist, or ffmpeg is unable to access it, even if it is there.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cap-set-cv2-cap-prop-pos-msec-changes-to-unreachable-timestamp/6561

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yea that is my post, I tried to widen my reach. I'm using a CNN for feature extraction and I didn't want to feed it frames where nothing of meaning is happening but well, I guess I'll just read them all. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz 2 questions as a side note, why does it behaves that way? how `cap.set` goes from 800ms to that number? I saw some examples of people here that claimed it worked (just the starting time though, didn't see one with end time).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz And the 2nd one is what do you mean by "use ffprobe -of json and show format and streams of your video file"? is it about extracting metadata from the video file? you said it as a general suggestion or as something related to seeking?

Comment: Can you check/debug your starttime and endtime and multiplied values? If you assume the values to be 13k <= 4k but you enter the loop there is probably something wrong with your assumptions.

Comment: @Micka I don't enter the loop, that's the problem, I set the starting point to `800` milliseconds, but as I step over to the next line `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` returns `13346` milliseconds when I evaluate it in the debugging console, which is longer than my video, but I can still manually before stepping into the loop line to use `cap.read()` to read a frame and get one.

Comment: Does it work if you choose to work with pos_frames instead of frame_pos_ms? E.g. cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_time*60)

Comment: @Micka It did! but why? sorry for being stubborn on this one, I'm just trying to understand its behavior.

Comment: I dont know. Maybe timestamps in your video are broken or sth.. counting frames would be less error prone. I didnt have problems with setting to timestamp positions in a video in the past, though.

Comment: For debugging you could try to start at 0 and just read it frame by frame and print the current timestamp from the cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) and compare those values to reference 60 fps frame steps.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz [This is](https://gist.github.com/ImSo3K/072566a76e99d63184ed85782e026e09) the `.json` file I got. And yes I can slice the frames list to discard unneeded frames, I just wanted to explore a more 'automated' feature first.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I just saw your edit, so as a more robust thumb rule, should I just read all the frames and manipulate that list or I can use Micka's way too?

Comment: how did you manage to shove H.264 content into an AVI? whatever the source was, best not to use AVI anywhere. it's an ancient format that can't deal with modern data anymore. -- I'd be interested in `-show_packets -select_streams v` to see the succession of frame types

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That's the data I have been provided with by our researchers but thanks for the tip!

Comment: really, best to just read all frames and discard what you don't need. some formats (anything intra-coded) are easier to seek in than others. some containers are easier to seek in than others.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yea that is what I'm going to do, anyway [here is](https://gist.github.com/ImSo3K/c70f29b734d28919ac162be676b1cbbf) what you asked for

Comment: I see _eight_ keyframes. that's not much. you'll have a granularity of about half a second (30 frames) for seeking in this file (assuming all the software cooperates).